# PDFsharp - Image drawn with transparency

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am currently working on a PDF generator. I need to first draw the background image and then draw a dark layer with 85 percent of transparency. I can draw it nicely, but when I want to draw two images after that, those images also get the transparency and that is not what I want.

```
XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb((int)(.85 * 255), 255, 255, 255));
DrawPageBackground(gfx,backgroundImage,page.Width.Value,page.Height.Value);
gfx.DrawRectangle(b,0,0,gfx.PageSize.Width,gfx.PageSize.Height );
gfx.DrawImage(otherImage,25,25);
```

Is there any reason why I can't just draw the images without the transparency? Is it just something simple that I am not doing right now?

Thanks.

Comment: The transparency you set for the brush (which is not used in your code snippet) has no effect on the transparency of the image.

Images are drawn with the transparency set in the image.

Comment: The image has a transparent background, the 'logo' itself is not transparent (as it is white text). But the GraphicsState of the XGraphics object needs to be restored after the drawing of the transparent dark layer to fix this problem. I do not know why the drawing of the image is affected by the brush, even as I know that the image can't be set to a lower transparency.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam: The method DrawPageBackground (which content can be seen in my own answer) only resizes an background image to the correct resolution to vertically fit the pdf page.

Answer (score 1):

I did successfully fix this issue by saving the XGraphicsState before the drawing of the background with darkened layer. After the drawing I used the XGraphicsState to restore and draw the images without any transparency. See the following piece of code.

```
XGraphicsState state = gfx.Save();
XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb((int)(.85 * 255), 255, 255, 255));
DrawPageBackground(gfx,backgroundImage,page.Width.Value,page.Height.Value);
gfx.DrawRectangle(b,0,0,gfx.PageSize.Width,gfx.PageSize.Height );
gfx.DrawImage(otherImage,25,25);
gfx.Restore(state);
```

The method DrawPageBackground:

```
private static void DrawPageBackground(XGraphics gfx, XImage image, double pageWidth, double pageHeight)
{
    if (image.Size.Width > pageWidth)
        gfx.DrawImage(image, CalculateDiffImageCenterToPageCenter(image,pageWidth), 0, CalculateBackgroundImageWidth(image,pageHeight), pageHeight);
    else
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, CalculateBackgroundImageWidth(image, pageHeight),pageHeight);
}
```

This is just an helper method to draw the background image to the right scale and center it.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam: I added the method in the reaction. It is not a method which could affect the problem. Also that helper method also depends on a couple of helper methods which only contain mathematical stuff (calculating the width and height of objects in relationship with another metric size)

Comment: The side effect comes from brush `b` (origin not shown in the snippet) and not from brush `brush` (created but not used in the snippet). Could be a bug in PDFsharp. For the time being, encapsulate the call to `DrawRectangle()` with `Save()` and `Restore()` to avoid the side effect.

Comment: Brush `b` is just the following: `XSolidBrush b = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(169, 0, 0, 0));`. I indeed encapsulate the call to `DrawRectangle()` with `Save()` and `Restore()`. But I find this very strange and, I assume, not wanted behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm what I wrote in a comment: it is a bug that the transparency set for a brush was also applied to the images.

With version 1.50.3915-beta2 published earlier this week, this bug was fixed.

Using `Save()` and `Restore()` is a suitable workaround for earlier versions, but with the latest version this workaround is no longer needed.